# changing datatype of dynamically generated columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a temporary table in which the columns are dynamically generated using pivot.As I am using the pivot function the columns by themselves are of int datatype. the values for the columns are either 0 or 1. Now I want to update 1 with 'Y' and 0 with 'N'. but I am getting conversion error while doing so. please help.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, you need to convert the int values to varchar.

```
set @a= 'select  * into ##test2   
from ##test  
PIVOT  (  Count(OtherConditionCode)  
FOR [CodeDescription] IN  ('+@cols+')  )  AS p';
```

I don't know all your column names but it should look something like this, assuming col4 is the one with the 1|0.

```
set @a = '
  select col1, col2, col3,
    case when col4 = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as col4
  from ##test
  PIVOT ...
```

Comment: The columns are getting generated dynamically so do not have column names

Comment: @user1226569 - actually, the column names are not dynamic.

Comment: so can u plz tell me how should I mention all the columns when i have to update all the dynamically generated columns?

Comment: Since I have no clue what columns exist in the tables GridSurveyType, CGEHistoryReport, SurveyPremiseOtherCondition or LuMasterData OR which one you want to convert to Y|N, I couldn't even begin to tell you how to "mention all the column".